# left join without duplicate values using MIN()

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, join

I have a table_1:

```
id  custno
1   1
2   2
3   3
```

and a table_2:

```
id  custno  qty  descr
1   1       10   a
2   1       7    b
3   2       4    c
4   3       7    d
5   1       5    e
6   1       5    f
```

When I run this query to show the minimum order quantities from every customer:

```
SELECT DISTINCT table_1.custno,table_2.qty,table_2.descr 
FROM table_1 
LEFT OUTER JOIN table_2 
    ON  table_1.custno = table_2.custno AND  qty = (SELECT MIN(qty) FROM table_2 
WHERE table_2.custno = table_1.custno   )
```

Then I get this result:

```
custno qty  descr
1      5    e 
1      5    f
2      4    c
3      7    d
```

Customer 1 appears twice each time with the same minimum qty (& a different description) but I only want to see customer 1 appear once. I don't care if that is the record with 'e' as a description or 'f' as a description.

Comment: What server/version are you using?

Comment: Yes, the key is that you needed to use a group by in your query.

Comment: I am using SQL server 2008

Comment: With any JOIN, if one of the tables has multiples of the joined value (custno) then you will have multiple results for that key unless you GROUP BY.

Comment: Repost, **BY YOU**, of post:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19915849/left-join-of-with-without-duplicate-records-only-showing-1-minimum-value   Why didn't you edit the question on your first post?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Generic" SQL way:

```
SELECT table_1.custno,table_2.qty,table_2.descr 
FROM table_1, table_2 
WHERE table_2.id = (SELECT TOP 1 id 
                    FROM table_2 
                    WHERE custno = table_1.custno 
                    ORDER BY qty )
```

SQL 2008 way (probably faster):

```
SELECT custno, qty, descr 
FROM
(SELECT 
    custno, 
    qty, 
    descr,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY custno ORDER BY qty) RowNum
    FROM table_2
) A
WHERE RowNum = 1
```

Comment: This does the trick; I will transpose this into my real code. Thx!

Comment: @TimSchmelter Thanks - was more concerned about the `ROW_NUMBER` syntax and forgot the table name and alias.

Comment: Please don't teach people to use non-ANSI-92 syntax :(  what's wrong with using an explicit JOIN and including the correlated sub-query in the predicate?

Answer (score 3):

First of all... I'm not sure why you need to include `table_1` in the queries to begin with:

```
select  custno, min(qty) as min_qty 
from    table_2 
group   by custno;
```

But just in case there is other information that you need that wasn't included in the question:

```
select table_1.custno, ifnull(min(qty),0) as min_qty
from   table_1 
       left outer join table_2 
          on table_1.custno = table_2.custno 
group  by table_1.custno;
```

Comment: Not if you want `descr` as well.

Comment: @DStanley: I thought OP said he doesn't care about descr:  _I don't care if that is the record with 'e' as a description or 'f' as a description._

Comment: I take that to mean "I don't care _which_ record."  I presume the OP wants _one_ of the values.

Comment: even without descr it returns the highest value (10) instead of the minimum value (5)

Comment: There's 2 records with qty 5 and I only want 1 of those 2 records, no matter which one

Answer (score 0):

If you use `SQL-Server` you could use `ROW_NUMBER` and a `CTE`:

```
WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT table_1.custno,table_2.qty,table_2.descr,
       RN = ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY table_1.custno
                                Order By table_2.qty ASC)
    FROM table_1 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN table_2 
        ON  table_1.custno = table_2.custno 
)
SELECT custno, qty,descr
FROM CTE
WHERE RN = 1
```

<kbd>[**Demolink**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/41ee1/1/0)</kbd>